# Accessing private functions on another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a function named `private void QuizReset()` on a form called `FormMain` and I was wondering if there was a way to access it on a form named `Form2` without getting build errors? Might seem like a really simple question or something I'm missing, but I've tried changing it from private to public and I mustn't be doing it right as I get build errors and such. I'm all up for modifying it if it can be done without errors. If anyone could help me out that'd be great.

Thank you.

The current code for the function is:

```
private void QuizReset()
    {
        //resets the difficulty selection control and shows it again upon resetting the quiz
        difficultySelectionControl.Reset();
        difficultySelectionControl.BringToFront();

        btnNext.Enabled = false;
        lblStatus.Text = "Please select a difficulty";

        iCorrectACount = 0;
        iCurrentQIndex = 0;
    }
```

Comment: How are you "accessing" it?  Show some code.

Comment: No way since it is private

Comment: what are the build errors?

Comment: This will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719988/accessing-a-function-in-another-form-c-sharp

Comment: "changing it to public" is the right answer so you must have some other problem; we need code & actual error messages to help.

Comment: @CL4PTR4P I tried to access it by typing in the name of the function `QuizReset();` but obviously that didn't work as it's on another form. I understand I have to modify it from a private void to something else but not sure what.

Comment: This will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719988/accessing-a-function-in-another-form-c-sharp

Comment: @user2141272 If you'd post some code, we could help you more.

Comment: make it static or initialize form2 before trying to access it...or create a baseForm class of your own so that all forms can have that method or use reflection :)

Comment: Show us your code in Form2 that is trying to call Form1.

Comment: I tried changing the function on the MainForm to `public void QuizReset()` and tried to access it in Form2 by typing `MainForm.QuizReset();` but I get the error `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Quizzological.MainForm.QuizReset()'`

Comment: that syntax is for a static method call. make the function public static and then call it like MainForm.QuizReset();

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer Just `public static` or `public static void`? I get errors now that are `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Quizzological.MainForm.btnNext'` and I get these errors for `btnNext`, `difficultySelectionControl` twice (I have `difficultySelectControl.Reset()` and `BringToFront()`) and `lblStatus`

Comment: a static method can only call other static methods and can use only static members of a class. if you can share a bit more on what you are trying to achieve, then more people will be able to help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the method it can't be private. `static public` is a simple work around. Then you can call it with `MainForm.LoadQuiz()`. Another option is to move the logic into a helper class.

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a public common class. Then put LoadQuiz function as a private static method that belongs to that class. You can also make LoadQuiz a static public, which is quick and dirty. I don't recommend that, because exposing methods publically could cause memory and allocation problems down the road.

Comment: I tried to do this but then got errors such as `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Quizzological.MainForm.btnNext'` and `The name 'QuizReset' does not exist in the current context`. The code for the function is in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot put this function in common static class, because, if I understand right, the function use a controls of the form(`btnNext.Enabled = false;`). This mean that function can/must be used only with instance of the `FormMain` class.

If you want call this function from `Form2`, then `Form2` must to have a reference of `FormMain`.

My approach will be next:

Create a variable in `Form2`:

```
private FormMain frmMain;
```

Then create a constructor of  `Form2` where i assign a reference of `FormMain` in `Form2`

```
public Form2(FormMain inFrmMain)
{
    this.frmMain = inFrmMain;
}
```

Code for opening of `Form2` will be then:

```
Form2 frm2 = New Form2(this);
frm2.Show();
```

After this you can call your `FormMain` function from `Form2`:

```
this.frmMain.QuizReset()
```

And of course, at first change function `QuizReset` to public